# Optimization of querys in django eliminating querys duplicates

Tags: django

I'm trying to get the number of products that have each category, but each category is in turn parent of other categories, so I want to know how many children have that category and their daughter categories, I have simplified the query to the maximum in the following way, but in the django debug I keep showing that I have 66 querys duplicates.

How can I eliminate these duplications?

With the first line of views.py, he managed to get the number of products in a category, but the problem is essentially to tell him to return me from the category and his daughters.

models.py

```
class Categoria(models.Model):
   nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
   padre = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, 
           related_name='cat_padre')
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', 
                                    auto_now_add=True)
   upd_date = models.DateTimeField('date updated', auto_now=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.nombre + ' ' + self.pais.iso

class Producto(models.Model):
   nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
   categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria)
```

views.py

```
cats = Categoria.objects.annotate(num_productos=Count('producto')).filter(pais__iso=pais, padre__isnull=True).order_by('-num_productos')

for c in cats:
     num_p = Producto.objects.filter(categoria__padre=c).count()
     c.num_productos += num_p

 contexto = {
    'categorias_padre': cats,
}

return render(request, 'web/pruebitas/product.html', contexto)
```

Django debug:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "web_producto" INNER JOIN "web_categoria" ON ("web_producto"."categoria_id" = "web_categoria"."id") WHERE "web_categoria"."padre_id" = '790'

Duplicated 62 times.

```
Conexión: default
/home/luis/PycharmProjects/lco_web/web/middleware.py in __call__(29)
  response = self.get_response(request)
/home/luis/PycharmProjects/lco_web/web/views.py in index(11)
  return categoria(request, '', '/')
/home/luis/PycharmProjects/lco_web/web/views.py in categoria(170)
  'categorias': categorias(pais, categoria.id if categoria else 0),
/home/luis/PycharmProjects/lco_web/web/views.py in categorias(29)
  num_p = Producto.objects.filter(categoria__padre=c).count()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by using reverse lookup to child categories using `cat_padre` and `Count` with `distinct=True`.

```
cats = Categoria.objects.annotate(
    num_productos=Count('cat_padre__producto', distinct=True) + 
                  Count('producto', distinct=True)).filter(
                      pais__iso=pais, padre__isnull=True).order_by('-num_productos')
```

P.S. I have tested that on fake data so please compare what you have got earlier with what returns this query.

Comment: It works like a charm.

So we reduce the load time from 1.10 seconds to 945ms and CPU use from 435ms to 345ms, is the correct answer.

Could you please explain more thoroughly how you came to this conclusion, and if there are more where you can read about it, I would like to learn more about this topic, because I have very bad the issue of querys

Comment: @Luis I have played around with your models, django orm and sql which it builds. I would suggest to read django docs about queryset and orm functions which they provide plus some book about your underlying database.

Comment: Hello @bellum, now I have a related problem, having more than 15000 products and 2500 categories, the query that you mentioned takes more than 4 seconds, which collapses the web, you can think of some idea how you could place the categories and products to avoid these times, since I need to show only categories that have more than 10 products, which will be the important ones.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: @Luis Hi. I would suggest you to create another question as I have no time atm to check. Good luck.

Comment: @Luis the solution most apparent is to add `db_index=True` to your model fields you are querying. Outside of that perhaps using `values()` speeds this up. I have a DB table with over 4 million rows and indexes took off a few seconds. `iterator` also took off a bit, I'm thinking `values` or pure SQL may be best for really large queries containing tons of rows